# Connecting / Soldering a Switch to Breadboard / PCB

Tags: switches, soldering, toggle-switch

I'm pretty new to electronics and I have just found these toggle switches. But I can't figure out how the connectors on the bottom are called in the english language .. :) And also, is there a way to connect those to a standard breadboard (without soldering a wire to it)? And if you were to solder one on a PCB, how would you do it? Through-Hole?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a link to its datasheet, or part number and manufacturer? Judging from the screw-thread, and small lug visible abve the washer, it is designed for panel mount. However the datasheet should make that clear.

Comment: There are usually PCB mounting versions of these available. They have pins more suitable for PCB soldering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called terminals. They are meant to be used with quick disconnect blade terminal connectors. See the thin ones on the bottom right. Alternatively you solder directly to them, by tinning, and sticking a wire to it with solder.

[image]

Switch with similar terminals, paired with quick disconnects:

[image]

They are not typically soldered directly to a pcb, as these types of switches are meant to be Panel mounted, not board mounted. They will need a custom pcb mounting hole if you wanted to use a pcb, as they will not fit in a standard 0.1" round hole. If you etch a pcb, or enlarge a hole, you could then solder them as you would any through hole part.

**If you really don't want to solder to them, use a quick disconnect terminal plug, or you can use alligator or test clips.** Worst case, use wire wrap, but that may not be the most stable or secure connection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those connections are not intended for quick-disconnect. They are intended entirely for soldering.

Comment: @Passerby:  I don't think those switches are meant for use with Faston(tm) or similar terminals - the solder lugs are much too thick.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast there are multiple sizes of quick disconnects, as pictured, the one on the bottom right with the black wire would fit. I have anti-vandal switches with these thin quick disconnects. Not all switches use typical auto sized blade terminals (blue quick disconnect in picture)

Comment: @PeterBennett see http://www.primochill.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/PSW-BMV16-R-W_kit-800x640.jpg

Comment: The terminals under the O.P.'s switch are solder lugs.  Not intended for quick-disconnect therminals.  If we had the datasheet for the O.P.'s switch, it would say something about terminals.  In lieu of *the* datasheet, [here's a switch with similar terminals](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/M2012SS1W01/360-1801-ND/1006880) that mentions "Solder Lug" explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

If you are a cheap-skate, you can grind off one side of the lugs leaving a 'pin' that can be thru-hole soldered.

Comment: Or fit in a breadboard. Novel idea. +1

Comment: downvoter: why the downvote? I commonly did this myself to anchor some strangely terminated switches (certainly *not* attachable to any connector I know of) to my prototype boards - also, FWIW, sometimes it's simply better to drill a hole a bit larger than in the usual inch raster, and simply put it and solder the terminations as with any other piece...

Answer (score 1):

That's a panel-mount switch. Designed to be mounted through a hole on a panel, with wires soldered to the terminals.

Answer (score 1):

That style of termination is often called a 'solder lug' and it is not intended to be used to solder the switch to a PCB.
The sort of toggle switch with PCB-suitable pins looks like this:[image]

But if I had one of your switches and I wanted to plug it into a breadboard I would probably get some stiff solid-core wire and solder a short length onto each lug.
You probably could shoe-horn one of those onto a PCB if you designed the PCB with holes large enough to fit the lugs ...

Answer (score 1):

What you're showing is a panel-mount switch with solder tabs. You obviously can't plug this into a breadboard, because the tabs are way too big.

If you need to solder a similar switch to the PCB, you would look for part that is designed for PCB mounting, either through hole or surface mount. Something like this:

[image]

But even this switch will not go into the breadboard easily. Soldering wires would be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

They are typically called solder lug terminals and are intended for wires to be soldered to them. They will not fit in a breadboard; if you want to use them with a breadboard, you should solder wires or perhaps header terminals if the pitch lines up.

Although not really intended for it, they could be placed directly in a PCB with the correct holes, but typically you would solder wires to the terminals, and then terminate the wires elsewhere or solder them directly to a board.

Answer (score 0):

I call the connection points "terminals" or "solder lugs".

I think the only way to use a switch like this with a plastic breadboard is to solder #22 or #24 solid wires to the lugs, then insert the wires in the breadboard.

I would not use a switch like that in a PC board.  You can get the switches with "solder tails" that can be soldered into a PC board (but those solder tails are too big to fit in a breadboard).P

Answer (score 0):

Those are wire terminals, and as you might guess from the name they are intended to connect to wires, not PCBs. A bare conductor is inserted into the hole, then bent back so as to form a secure mechanical connection. Then the wire is soldered, making an electrical connection.

The connecting lugs are so large that it's difficult to make a PCB layout that will work for them - the holes would be very large and very close to overlapping.